# El plugin maven-shade-plugin no me genera el Fat JAR, ¿por que?

Tags: java, maven

Lo que pretendo es obtener un único *jar* con todas las dependencias de la aplicación pero recibo una `NoClassDefFoundException` al momento de ejecutarse el `main`.

Comprobando el contenido del *jar* en cuestión después de ejecutar `mvn package` o `mvn clean package` efectivamente éste se encuentra incompleto, faltan los recursos y demás `.class` de las dependencias.

Esta es la parte de mi *pom.xml* con el *plugin*:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <executions>
             <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
            <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>io.quake3.api.AppLauncher</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- mas plugins... -->

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Si hay algún detalle mas que deba incluir lo editaré; No le encuentro la vuelta :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que has realizado la configuración del *plugin* dentro de la sección `build > pluginManagement` y deberías haberlo hecho dentro de `build > plugins`.

Según la [documentación oficial del *plugin*](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) el propósito de esta sección (`pluginManagement`) es "configurar la construcción de los proyectos que hereden de este". Esto quiere decir que las configuraciones de *plugins* que realices en esta sección no tendrán efecto en tu proyecto y por lo tanto es como si no las hubieras hecho.

Para solucionarlo simplemente mueve dicha configuración a la sección `build > plugins`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>test.Test</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: +1, ya funciona.