# Error al iniciar contenedor de aplicación Java Spring Boot con gradle

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, gradle

estoy intentando arrancar un contenedor de una api rest que hice con java sprint boot y a la hora de arrancar sale el siguiente error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

17:36:36.665 [main] INFO co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi.JudicialApiApplication - Starting JudicialApiApplication using Java 17.0.1 on 5c64445e185d with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
17:36:36.667 [main] DEBUG co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi.JudicialApiApplication - Running with Spring Boot, Spring
17:36:36.669 [main] INFO co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi.JudicialApiApplication - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
17:36:36.670 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi.JudicialApiApplication
17:36:36.777 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1445d7f
17:36:36.790 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
17:36:36.875 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/base/configs/ApplicationConfig.class]
17:36:36.883 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/base/configs/ApplicationProps.class]
17:36:36.890 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/base/utils/ResponseDTOService.class]
17:36:36.891 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/configs/AuthEntryPointJwt.class]
17:36:36.893 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/configs/JwtUtils.class]
17:36:36.904 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/configs/WebSecurityConfig.class]
17:36:36.951 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/controllers/AuthController.class]
17:36:36.966 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/repositories/ConfirmationTokenRepository.class]
17:36:36.967 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/repositories/RoleRepository.class]
17:36:36.968 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/repositories/UserRepository.class]
17:36:36.970 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/services/impl/BuildEmailService.class]
17:36:36.972 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/services/impl/ConfirmationTokenService.class]
17:36:36.974 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/services/impl/EmailService.class]
17:36:36.975 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/services/impl/RoleService.class]
17:36:36.976 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/services/impl/UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]
17:36:36.978 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/services/impl/UserService.class]
17:36:36.979 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/utils/CreateRoles.class]
17:36:36.980 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/utils/DateUtil.class]
17:36:37.853 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
17:36:37.864 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages'
17:36:37.865 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages - @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
17:36:37.868 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Scanning for JPA repositories in packages co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi.
17:36:37.901 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/repositories/ConfirmationTokenRepository.class]
17:36:37.902 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/repositories/RoleRepository.class]
17:36:37.902 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/repositories/UserRepository.class]
17:36:37.960 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/co/com/ajbusiness/judicialapi/security/services/impl/UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]
17:36:37.986 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 115 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
17:36:38.236 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer'
17:36:38.246 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer$DependsOnDatabaseInitializationPostProcessor'
17:36:38.247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'emBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor'
17:36:38.256 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
17:36:38.257 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'conversionServicePostProcessor'
17:36:38.292 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'preserveErrorControllerTargetClassPostProcessor'
17:36:38.294 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
17:36:38.294 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory'
17:36:38.300 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
17:36:38.301 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
17:36:38.304 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
17:36:38.305 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
17:36:38.306 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinder'
17:36:38.306 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinderFactory'
17:36:38.310 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
17:36:38.368 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'methodValidationPostProcessor'
17:36:38.392 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' via factory method to bean named 'environment'
17:36:38.395 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.methodValidationExcludeFilter'
17:36:38.409 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor'
17:36:38.411 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' via factory method to bean named 'environment'
17:36:38.414 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'webServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor'
17:36:38.415 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'errorPageRegistrarBeanPostProcessor'
17:36:38.416 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor'
17:36:38.418 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor'
17:36:38.419 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource'
17:36:38.419 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration'
17:36:38.420 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
17:36:38.420 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
17:36:38.470 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionAttributeSource'
17:36:38.475 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionInterceptor'
17:36:38.476 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'transactionInterceptor' via factory method to bean named 'transactionAttributeSource'
17:36:38.496 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' via factory method to bean named 'transactionAttributeSource'
17:36:38.496 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' via factory method to bean named 'transactionInterceptor'
17:36:38.510 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'objectPostProcessor'
17:36:38.510 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration'
17:36:38.512 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'objectPostProcessor' via factory method to bean named 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6a03bcb1' 
17:36:38.567 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
17:36:38.568 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration'
17:36:38.570 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
17:36:38.570 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari'
17:36:38.572 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties'
17:36:38.575 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.BoundConfigurationProperties'
17:36:38.609 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'dataSource' via factory method to bean named 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties'
17:36:38.612 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating be
an with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dat
aSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
17:36:38.621 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested except
ion is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
        at co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi.JudicialApiApplication.main(JudicialApiApplication.java:11)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method fa
iled; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:182)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:123)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Tengo el siguiente archivo **DockerFile**

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/jdk:java17-21.3.0
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

y la siguiente configuracion en mi ***build.gradle***

***build.gradle:***

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.34.0'
}

group = 'co.com.ajbusiness'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi.JudicialApiApplication"
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from {
        configurations.resolvableImpl.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

configurations {
    resolvableImpl.extendsFrom(implementation)
    resolvableImpl.canBeResolved(true)
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

docker {
    name "${project.name}"
    dockerfile file('./Dockerfile')
    copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*", "app.jar")
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "app.jar"])
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation group: 'jakarta.validation', name: 'jakarta.validation-api', version: '2.0.2'
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.3'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.0'
    implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:4.6.1'
    implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.6.1'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.6.10.Final'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Parece ser un error de base de datos, pero cuando corro la aplicacion con el comando

> ./gradlew bootRun

funciona correctamente y trabaja de maravilla con la base de datos.

llevo varios dias intentando solucionarlo, cabe recalcar que tengo la instancia de mysql dockerizada en mi equipo local y estos son los comandos que ejecuto

para buildiar la app:

> ./gradlew clean build

para generar la imagen apartir del jar generado con el build:

> ./gradlew docker

y para intentar correr el contenedor:

> docker run -it judicialapi

de ante mano agradezco cualquier ayuda prestada.

Comment: por que tienes tu driver de mysql como runtime? no es mal plan... pero quiero saber si buscas hacer un uber jar o de que manera piensas poner el driver en el classpath

Comment: deberia cambiarse entonces a compile?

Comment: lo agregue como implementation y sale el mismo error

Comment: era de esperarse, ya que algo me dice que no generas un fat jar o uber jar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/454939/el-plugin-maven-shade-plugin-no-me-genera-el-fat-jar-por-que

Comment: si lo genero, solo que no lo llamo fatJar, solo lo sobrescribo en el taks del jar

Comment: y como sabes que es un uber jar?

Comment: jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "co.com.ajbusiness.judicialapi.JudicialApiApplication"
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from {
        configurations.resolvableImpl.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

Comment: ahi encapsulo los zip, me base en la documentacion de baeldung https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

Comment: si usas spring data puedes guiarte un poco de mi repo aunque este esta con maven: https://github.com/javatlacati/Inventarios